# Building a C++ Android application with clang and Manifest.xml

Tags: android, c++, clang, manifest

I have simple main.cpp file which prints hello world.
To run this on an Android device I do the following:

```
/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tony/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot main.cpp

adb push a.out /data/local/tmp
adb shell /data/local/tmp/a.out
```

How can I compile this app with an manifest file?

Comment: You can use android studio also.

Comment: But I would built with qt gui.

Comment: That information is good, put all other relevant data about your task (error logs etc.). It is much  easiest to found someone to help you.

Comment: Ok I found a solution. I have to build an complete apk. How can I close this question?

Comment: Post answer for you question it is regular practice for stackoverflow . Help others with who have the similar problems. Same procedure just like normal answering.